# pandas groupby conditional count with string condition

Tags: pandas, group-by, count

I have a dataframe with columns

```
year docnr   code
2000 doc1 T1
2000 doc1 T2
2000 doc2 F1
2000 doc2 F1
2000 doc2 F1
2001 doc3 T1
2001 doc2 F1
2001 doc2 F1
```

I would like to use groupby year and docnr in order to count per year the number of documents that contains at least once the code containing "T"

So:

```
2000 doc1 T1
2000 doc1 T2
```

counts in 2000 for one

```
2000 doc1 T1
2000 doc1 H
```

also counts for one

```
2000 doc1 G4
2000 doc1 P3
```

counts in 2000 for 0

my try looks like this:
(if f is the dataframe)

```
f.groupby(["year","docnr"])['code'].apply(lambda x: any("T" in x)).reset_index()
```

this does not work.
And I don't understand why.

POST EDIT

The result expected is a dataframe with Index the years and column the country of the above specified, I.e. how many documents contain at least once code starting by T

In the particular case above it would be
2000 1
2001 1

EDIT 2
Is this easier to do in polars?

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: hard to know what you want.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you could mask the docs that don't meet the condition and use [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
out = (df['docnr']
       .where(df['code'].str.startswith('T')) # mask docs other than "T"
       .groupby(df['year']).nunique()         # unique (valid) docs per year
      )
```

Output:

```
year
2000    1
2001    1
Name: docnr, dtype: int64
```

Intermediate before aggregation:

```
0    doc1
1    doc1
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    doc3
6     NaN
7     NaN
Name: docnr, dtype: object
```

Output if you replace `2001 doc3 T1` by `2001 doc3 X1`:

```
year
2000    1
2001    0
Name: docnr, dtype: int64
```

If you don't care about years with 0 documents, simplify the code to:

```
out = (df[df['code'].str.startswith('T')]
       .groupby('year')['docnr'].nunique()
      )
```

Output (in case of no match in 2001):

```
year
2000    1
Name: docnr, dtype: int64
```